# How does angular universal handle observables and how long wait for data

Tags: angular, angular-universal

How does angular universal handle observables and at which moment (point) will universal stop waiting for data?

I know that angular universal waits for some HTTP requests (observable) but I do not know what is logic behind it, and how universal decides when to stop waiting?

Comment: I am also interested in a complete answer. For a little bit of insight, it might be worth checking out the last to sections in the "Gotchas" section: https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/main/docs/gotchas.md#application-is-slow-or-worse-wont-render